# execute a function when a link is clicked

Tags: php

basically i want to have a `link` inside a `div` when clicked it will display a `<form>`

```
<sidebar>
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <a href="display.php"> Display </a>
  <hr>

  //display here 

</sidebar>
```

display.php

```
function display() {
 $test = echo '<input type="text" name="text">';
return 
}
```

the logic goes like, if i clicked the `href="display.php"` it will display the `function display();`

how can i display the returned value in `display()` function below `<hr>`

i cant seem to figure our the correct logic for it,

```
<hr>
if (display() == true) {
     $test = echo '<input type="text" name="text">';
return
}
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: if i undertand well you will need javascript to do that, you want to click a link and then a form must apear in the area of `//display here`?

Comment: sorry, how would i display the returned value in my display() after the `<hr>`

Comment: Does the page need to go back to the server after it is clicked? OR do you actually want css show/hide?

Comment: You can't do that from what I understand from your question. You need to either refresh the page on click or use JavaScript to update it via AJAX. I would probably use a `<button>` vs a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that, you need to submit the request to the server in order to process and get back that echo, here the way you are doing won't work, either use a form or a link with a parameter(If you are using `GET` method) with get or post method, and by using `$_GET` or `$_POST`, you can execute the function.

Also your function is wrong, you cannot write an `echo` like that, it should be

```
function display() {
    $test = '<input type="text" name="text">';
    return $test;
}
```

For example

If you are using `GET` than link with a parameter is sufficient, say

```
<a href="display.php?display=true"> Display </a>

<?php
   if(!empty($_GET['true'])) {
      echo display();
   }
?>
```

Alternatively if you want to use a post method than you'll need a form as I specified before

```
<form method="post">
   <input type="submit" value="Display" name="display" />
</form>

<?php
   if(!empty($_POST['display'])) {
      echo display();
   }
?>
```

Comment: thank you! :) due to aesthetic purposes i needed to use `link` instead of a submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript for this.  Render the form always, hide is using using style='display:none;'.  Add a click handler to the link having it show the form when the link is clicked.  I recommend using jQuery to add the handler to make this task easier.